# unable to comare the output of the function in shell script

Tags: bash

I am trying to remove docker container and and store or compare the result but i am unable to do that  kindly let me know how to get the return value for further process

```
delete_the_container() {

 res= docker container rm -f $1 && echo "success" || echo "fail"
 echo "$?"

}

fielpos="./filename"

input="./filename"

while IFS= read -r line
do
   #echo "$line"

   res= $(delete_the_container $line)

   echo "$res"                  #not get the res value    

done < "$input"
```

Answer (score 0):

***$?*** returns code value of last command, the code below must help you

```
docker container rm -f $1
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then 
     ... code if rm command success ...
else
     ... code if rm command failed...
fi
```

Your line (I added ***$(...)*** to execute command) :

```sh
res= $(docker container rm -f $1 && echo "success" || echo "fail")
```

***res*** value can be "success" or "fail" but ***$?*** are all time 1 because last command are ***echo***.